# How can I reload a gridview onclientclick of another gridview's button?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, events, gridview

I have a modal popup that contains a gridview. On the click of a button inside of a grid i reload the gridview with the data that depends on the id of the row clicked in the gridview. I would have like to reload the gridview onclientclick but I couldn't find a way to do that. Is it possible to reload a gridview client-side without the user even knowing the page partially loaded?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what Matt Berseth is doing with gridview/detailsview, it might be of some help to you.

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/masterdetail_with_the_gridview.html

Comment: Just in case anyone else goes looking for the blog article, it's easiest to find it here:  http://web.archive.org/web/20081217132051/http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/04/masterdetail_with_the_gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you wrap your GridView & Button, in an updatePanel, inside the ModalPopup.

That way, your `_click` still fires and still updates the gridview but you won't experience a full page postback/submit.

Comment: That's a great idea. However, I do have it in an update panel and set the updatemode to "conditional". I just don't want to see it load on the page. I'll edit my question.